# Location of res/drawables in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I can't figure out the path to any of the res/drawables folders so that I can add images to them. I'm using eclipse to learn to build android apps, and have everything installed correctly, I just need help locating the folder. Whats the path you guys have?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a concept of workspace directory, where it stores all the projects. When eclipse is opened, user has to provide location of the workspace directory. In this directory, there will be a directory for each application/project. Inside each application/project directory, you can find res/drawables directory.

Answer (score 0):

First create a new Android Project. This will automatically generate a folder structure inside yor neww project.

You should be seing now

```
    Your Project (project folder)
           src (folder)
           ...
           gen (folder)
           res (folder)
             drawable (folder)
             layout (folder)
             values (folder)
             ...
```